# In the glade or on the glade?

Tags: prepositions

> They are dancing in/on the glade.

Which preposition is correct?

Oxforddictionaries.com gives the following definition of the word:

> An open space in a wood or forest.

So glade is a space, not a surface free from trees, and they are dancing *in* this space, not *on* the surface. Is it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, one is

> in a glade

since it surrounds you, similar to a valley.  With both glades and valleys one can not be "on" them.